# Как отправлять почту с помощью PHP

Tags: php, email

Не совсем понимаю как отправлять почту из PHP скрипта. Везде разрозненная информация, кто то пишет установить sendmail, кто то пишет что хватит PHPmailer. Не совсем понимаю логику самого процесса, скрипт выдает сообщение и через какие инстанции оно должно пройти что бы попасть на тот же Mail? И что для этого надо кроме Apache и Php?? Может есть источник представляющий картину целиком?

Comment: Картина целиком - вам нужно подготовить письмо(например на php), и кто то его должен отправить, ни php ни apache этого(отправку) не делают, для этого можно использовать внешний сервер(например тот же mail.ru) или установить свой сервер( PHPmailer\sendmail). Плюсом к этому надо настроить выбранный способ в php.ini

Comment: А как Php скрипт получает доступ к внешнему серверу(тот же mail.ru), это описывается в php.ini, и если да то что и как настроить надо? И как я понимаю Phpmailer это библиотека, а Sendmail это почтовый агент...

Comment: Описывается через настройки smtp пртокола